# How long would someone last in excruciating pain while assisted by chemicals?

Tags: science-based, biochemistry, body-modification, torture

My setting is just like the real world, except for a twisted Excess God. Who demands rituals to exacerbate its Worshipers feelings, which he in turn feeds on.

There's just a problem, these rituals are supposed to go on for Days at a time, some of them are torture, the others are pleasurable.

For pleasurable ones to go on for days, other members will give them stimulants to be able to keep up without any sleep, norepinephrine if they start slowing down or not being in the mood, Beta blockers if hearth rate gets dangerous to prevent people from having hearth attacks to prevent death from happening until the end of the festival. This much I think I've figured out. They even use some external apparatus to do some of the work.

What can I do to keep the body from going into shock and conscious while causing excruciating pain for days, with current day technology ?

Bonus points if as soon as we stop what we are doing, they just drop dead. Even more, if they can be kept alive, disemboweled.

Comment: Sounds like a Slaneeshi pleasure cult...

Comment: The question becomes how to prevent _shock_ which leads to things shutting down and what is _shock_... it seems to happen in the brain, but maybe the approach is more complicated, such as keeping the body functioning properly and simply allowing the mind to suffer endlessly. The body doesn't care what's happening to the mind if it has what it needs, but the reverse is not so.

Comment: Maybe preventing the blood vessels in the brain from constricting. This is what happens when we go to sleep. Is there a chemical for that? Also, the neurons fill up with protein/waste gunk. Without clearing that after a few days, the neurons stop working.

Comment: Yeah... it's questions like this that are the reason we're all on the U.S. Homeland Security watch list.

Comment: Don't forget that beta blockers block the *beta adrenaline (epinephrine)* receptors - this cancels out quite a bit o the effect of epinephrine. It's worth looking-up the specific effects/interactions of your drugs for realistic worldbuilding.

Comment: @TheDemonLord That was where I took inspiration from Yes.

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. (nice name ROFL xD) Thanks, I'm not greatly educated in the area, I had no idea how Beta blockers reduced blood flow, thanks.

Comment: Chemicals as medication? Just ask anyone who's had a back injury ...

Comment: @BMF I would, if opioids didn't have the chance for respiratory failure, cardiac arrest, not being able to walk and lost of consciousness, I want a chemical (Drug/medication) that will help with dealing with shock, not with the pain, they are supposed to feel pain.

Comment: @Nolo So a starting point would be to somehow sabotage the system that informs the brain of the state of the body, right ?

Comment: Mmm, maybe that's a starting point, but the idea is that you _cannot_ turn that off, but must somehow prevent specific _consequences_ of it, like the heart stopping, the mind shutting off, and so on.

Comment: @JBH This is totally _not_ why we're on watch lists. We're on those lists because people actually _act_ on these kinds of ideas. If they simply didn't do that, there'd be no problems at all. But at some point the desire for power just becomes a hall of mirrors. Much harder to untangle it then and makes more sense to just stop and chill.

Comment: @Nolo Asserting that we're all on the DHS watch list is a very long-running joke on this Stack because we're willing to entertain questions about poisons, weapons of mass destruction, bombs, efficient ways to off people, etc. Every so often we get a question like this one that, reasonable for the Stack as it may be, causes people to shake their heads and wonder how many stephens king there are in the world.

Comment: @JBH ah, so it's haha funny :D damn, i really wanted on that list!

Comment: @JBH oh yeah, stephen king got me into this, then 40k rammed me head first into gory stories.

Answer (score 5):

You can keep going in excruciating pain for **many months**. This is how long some cancer treatments can last, while causing severe side effects throughout *on top of* whatever suffering the cancer was causing to begin with.

And this can be achieved with currently available technology, the withdrawal of treatment can hasten death, and the cancer-infested organs may be removed during treatment with the intention of keeping the patient alive afterwards, so it even matches your bonus conditions somewhat.